# Powershell: script doesn't return all rows

Tags: powershell

I would like to add Department AD property to all users exported from an application. There are a lot of app users who can't be found in AD. 
This script returns Department to the users found in AD and skips the ones not found in AD. I would like script to return all users(all rows) and for those not found "No AD users found". What am I missing?

```
$csvfile = 'C:\temp\app_users.csv'
$ADFoundUsers = $null;
$ADFoundUsers = Import-Csv -Path $csvfile | Select-Object * -First 100 |

ForEach-Object {    
    $FullName = $_.'FullName'   
    Get-ADUser -Filter "name -eq '$FullName'" -Properties *}    

    If ($ADFoundUsers -ne $null) {    
        $ADFoundUsers | select Name,Department;
    }    
    Else {    
        Write-Host "No AD users found";    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$ADFoundUsers` has always contained rows when you have run this code, it will never equal `$null` (be empty), so would never enter the `else` block.

Even then you would only ever see either all users name and departments *or* one instance of ‘No AD users found’. You need the `if-else` block to be inside the `foreach` block to return one instance of ‘not found’ per user. The indentation of your code makes it look like it already is, but actually the closing brace of the foreach is at the end of the `Get-ADUser...` line.

Also you have `Select-Object * -First 100` this shouldn’t be there unless you are testing if you want all users as it will limit your results

Comment: ThanX John. I have moved closing brace of the Get-ADuser line to the very end so the if-else block is inside foreach block but that doesn't help. I get No AD users found per row. Any ideas?